# Apple Pages underline

Tags: macos, pages, font

When I underline a word with Pages 5.5.3 on OS X.

For the fonts I use, the underline goes very close to the text, much closer than it is common with Microsoft Word.

Just as "tracking" controls how close the next line of text follows the previous, I want to adjust the "tracking" space to lower the underline.

Is there any way to control this and give more space between the text and the underline?

Comment: What version of pages and what OS is it running on? Pages runs in a web browser, on iOS and on OS X

Comment: Last version on desktop 5.5.3

Answer (score 1):

Pages does not expose this control and from experimentation using large font face sizing (96 and above), it appears the spacing between the underline and the characters varies on the typeface selected.

For example - see Courier and Courier New - the second font has a much larger spacing than the first.

It looks like you'd need a tool to edit the typeface or choose a typeface that matches your expectations. It is a bit surprising now that I look how close the underline hews to the characters for Pages default styles.

Answer (score -1):

Actually not (unable to find it on the interface).